# Comparing FilesNames only not content is my solution correct?

Tags: c#, hashset

we are transferring lots of docs/images and before actually saving this docs to sql server I want to compare 2 list of files.

1. My List of filePaths (will be a txtFile with a list of filepaths In it.Converted to hashset)
2. Their List of filePaths (will read on the fly and produce a hashset)

   ```
   public static HashSet<string> ToHashSet(this string rootDirectory)
   {
       const string searchPattern = "*.*";
       string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(rootDirectory, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
       return new HashSet<string>(files);
   }
   ```

So I am comparing MyHashSet against TheirHashSet.

Just getting a bit paranoid here and just want to double check if except does what I think it does.

Except="Given 2 hashsets compare all the filePaths and if the ones in the TheirList are not found in MyList produce a result"

I have written a small test that proves that except does find the diff.

Is this correct and best way to compare large files?

Dummy ProofOfConcept

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string rootDirectory = @"C:\Tests";
        HashSet<string> myHashSet= CreateDummyHashSet(rootDirectory,10);
        HashSet<string> theirHashSet= CreateDummyHashSet(rootDirectory, 12);

        IEnumerable<string> result = theirHashSet.Except(myHashSet);

        foreach (var file in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static HashSet<string> CreateDummyHashSet(string rootDirectory, int numberOfFiles)
    {
        var dummyHashSet = new HashSet<string>();
        const string extension = ".txt";
        const string fileName = "File";
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++)
        {
            string fullfileName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", fileName, i, extension);
            string path = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, fullfileName);
            dummyHashSet.Add(path);
        }
        return dummyHashSet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct and best way to compare large files?

You are not comparing large files, you are just comparing their names. Hashset is perfectly suited to do this operations on sets.

I would not advise using what sbrauen propose

```
var result = theirHashSet.Where(x => !myHashSet.Contains(x));
```

because it has to do **n** operations on **m** entries, **n** and **m** being number of entries in `theirHashSet` and `myHashSet` respectively. Hashset should be more performing with these actions. And what is actually better then `Except` is `ExceptWith` because `Except` is an extension method of `IEnumerable` whereas `ExceptWith` is a method in `HashSet<>`.

**EDIT:**

The difference is that `Except` returns a new `IEnumerable` collection whereas `ExceptWith` will remove equal entries from `theirHashSet`. Also `ExceptWith` is faster because it knows internals of `HashTable`, `Except` is just an extension method.

Here is what it looks like under the hood

**Except**

```
Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
foreach (TSource tSource in second)
{
    set.Add(tSource);
}
foreach (TSource tSource1 in first)
{
    if (!set.Add(tSource1))
    {
        continue;
    }

    yield return tSource1;
}
```

**ExceptWith**

```
foreach (T t in other)
{
    this.Remove(t);
}
```

You can see a difference immediately.

Comment: thanks for your time .Yes I am comparing just names!! I have read about it and I would not do "where(x...)".My problem is that I didnt quite understand the difference between except and exceptWith. I know sounds clear in english but all i want is produce a list of filenames that dont exist

Comment: Thanks.So ExpectWith will produce the same results but faster because is a method of hashset.Could not find "ExpectWhere" though

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = theirHashSet.Where(x => !myHashSet.Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is quite clear on this - it returns values from the first HashSet that are not in the second one.

> Is this correct and best way to compare large files?

However, in your case it does compare only the lists of file paths, not the content of the files. I.e. after the check you know that you have (or not) the files with the same name but not if the files are the same.

Comment: That is fine.All i need to compare if the filename are the same.Content does not matter for now